# Confused by the notation in $\Omega(g) =\infty\mathbb{1}[\|w_g\|_0>k]$

Tags: notation, machine-learning

$$\Omega(g) =\infty\mathbb{1}[\|w_g\|_0>k]$$

[(original image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xC4Pw.png)

(Note: The "$\Bbb{1}$" should be in the blackboard-bold style of, say, $\Bbb{Z}$, but it doesn't seem to render that way for me. --Blue)

I am sorry that I am confused by the symbol of Double-Struck Digit One, infinity symbol and the zero below the $w_g.$
Does **one** means identity matrix here or the function?:

- $1$  belong to set
- $0$  not belong to set

Why there is infinity before one?

What is the meaning of that zero outside the Normal Form?

This is from the paper ["Why Should I Trust You?" Explaining the Predictions of Any Classifier (PDF link via arxiv.org)](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1602.04938.pdf); p4, left, upper part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- $\mathbb{1}$ is the notation for the indicator function.
- The $\infty$ is multiplied to the indicator function.
- $\|v\|_0$ counts how many non-zero entries are there in $v$.

Comment: Thanks for your kind explanation! I understand~